# SQL SELECT Compression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, select

I'm writing a query with the following structure:

```
IF (SELECT 8) = (SELECT 9)
INSERT INTO Quality_Report VALUES ('USBL', 'IM SL Current Time Period',(SELECT 8),(SELECT 9),'Match',GETDATE())

ELSE INSERT INTO Quality_Report VALUES ('USBL', 'IM SL Current Time Period',(SELECT 8),(SELECT 9),'Not Matched',GETDATE())
```

The SELECT "8" and "9" will be replaced with SELECT statements that return numeric value (like below).

```
SELECT 
CASE when Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS) =0 then 0 else 
Sum(INVN_DOL) / Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS)end as [IM DSO Current Time Period]
FROM [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_ITEMDETAILS] 
LEFT JOIN [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_OpcoMaster]      ON OpCo_NBR = Opco
       WHERE FISC_WEEK = '37'
       AND FY17_Market = 'Southeast'
```

When I replace both my SELECT statements with the actual queries, I get this error though: Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Any reason I can't do this? Works fine with the dummy SELECT 8/9s.

Thanks,

Comment: Microsoft SQL (T-SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You showed us only one select stetement and it's another one that gives you an error.
Try this and you'll find that it produces no error:

```
    if (SELECT 
    CASE when Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS) =0 then 0 else 
    Sum(INVN_DOL) / Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS)end as [IM DSO Current Time Period]
    FROM [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_ITEMDETAILS] 
    LEFT JOIN [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_OpcoMaster]      ON OpCo_NBR = Opco
           WHERE FISC_WEEK = '37'
           AND FY17_Market = 'Southeast')
           =
     (SELECT 
    CASE when Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS) =0 then 0 else 
    Sum(INVN_DOL) / Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS)end as [IM DSO Current Time Period]
    FROM [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_ITEMDETAILS] 
    LEFT JOIN [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_OpcoMaster]      ON OpCo_NBR = Opco
           WHERE FISC_WEEK = '37'
           AND FY17_Market = 'Southeast')
    print 'this works'
```

In your another select statement **you have more than one field** (8,9 in my example), that's causes the error:

```
    if (SELECT 
        8, 9)
               =
         (SELECT 
        CASE when Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS) =0 then 0 else 
        Sum(INVN_DOL) / Sum(AVG_DLY_SLS_LST_35_DYS)end as [IM DSO Current Time Period]
        FROM [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_ITEMDETAILS] 
        LEFT JOIN [Mars_Bars_RAW].DBO.[LND_OpcoMaster]      ON OpCo_NBR = Opco
               WHERE FISC_WEEK = '37'
               AND FY17_Market = 'Southeast')
        print 'this works'
```